# Is there a Wikipedia API to get the images of all resolutions given an image file name?

Tags: wikipedia-api

For example, given File:Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg as input, the output would include:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png
- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/500px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png
- ...

Answer (score 1):

The original image is a vector, the urls you have provided link to the wikipedia thumbnail generator.
It will generate an image of any resolution you specify, you can just change the value in the url and it will generate an image of that size.

I don't know why you would want to use it however. You should just get the original image and scale it yourself to your own needs.